# Skiasharp draw rectangle arround bitmap

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, bitmap, skiasharp

I have a question. I have a skiasharp canvas with a few bitmaps. Those bitmaps are stored in a Dictionary with a few properties. Now I already created something that detects if a bitmap has been selected and when it is, I store the key of the bitmap from the dictionary in a variable called `SelectedBitmap`. Now I want to draw a rectangle arround the selected bitmap, but how can I do that?

To do that I need to know the bitmap size and coordinates, but the bitmap can be moved and scaled within the canvas.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you saying you can't do this because you don't know where your bitmap is located, or at what scale?  Or do you just not understand how to draw on a Skia canvas?

Comment: I don't know the location and scale

Comment: Why not?  If you need this data, then you should track the changes the user is making to the bitmap as they occur.